# Pairs Trading VBA Loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops, trading

I have a problem when I want to build a pairs trading automation using Excel VBA.

My strategy is to open a position (OTC_Sell or OTC_Buy) when the spreads of two stocks hit +/- 2 standard deviation, and to close a position (CTC_buy or CTC_sell) when the spreads of two stocks hit +/- 4 standard deviation or hit back to the mean. Once the position is closed, I can open another position once I received another open trade condition(OTC).

However, when I run the code, it seems that the loop only runs one time since I can only get one trade (highlighted in yellow).After this cell, I can only get zeros but no other trade signals. I re-run the code starting from that cell beside the original column and get another trade (highlighted in green).still, I get all zeros afterwards. Whereas I want to get all trade signals within one column.

```
Function SignalCTC(Price1, Price2, Mean, SD, StopLoss)
Dim i, j, k, m, n, o, p, numRows, numOTC, order, list, flag, finish
numRows = Price1.Rows.Count
Dim SignalColOTC()
ReDim SignalColOTC(numRows, 1)
Dim Price1Col()
ReDim Price1Col(numRows)
Dim Price2Col()
ReDim Price2Col(numRows)
Dim P_Ratio()
ReDim P_Ratio(numRows)
'Loop 1
For i = 1 To numRows
    P_Ratio(i) = Price1(i) / Price2(i)
Next i
UpperLim = Mean + (2 * SD)
LowerLim = Mean - (2 * SD)
Count = 0
flag = 0
For i = 1 To numRows
    If (Count = 0 And (P_Ratio(i) < UpperLim) And (P_Ratio(i) > LowerLim)) Then
    Count = 0
    flag = 0
    SignalColOTC(i, 1) = "Wait&See"
    ElseIf (Count = 0 And (P_Ratio(i) > UpperLim)) Then
        Count = 1
        flag = 1
        SignalColOTC(i, 1) = "Wait&See"
        ElseIf (Count = 0 And (P_Ratio(i) < LowerLim)) Then
            Count = 1
            flag = -1
            SignalColOTC(i, 1) = "Wait&See"
            ElseIf (Count = 1 And flag = 1 And (P_Ratio(i) < UpperLim) And (P_Ratio(i) > Mean)) Then
                Count = 0
                flag = 0
                SignalColOTC(i, 1) = "OTC_Sell"
                ElseIf (Count = 1 And flag = -1 And (P_Ratio(i) > LowerLim) And (P_Ratio(i) < Mean)) Then
                    Count = 0
                    flag = 0
                    SignalColOTC(i, 1) = "OTC_Buy"
                    Else: SignalColOTC(i, 1) = "Wait&See"
    End If
Next i
numOTC = 0
order = 0
list = 0
For i = 1 To numRows
    If (SignalColOTC(i, 1) = "OTC_Sell") Or (SignalColOTC(i, 1) = "OTC_Buy") Then
    numOTC = numOTC + 1
    Else: numOTC = numOTC
    End If
Next i
'Dim x
'Loop 2
    Dim SignalColCTC()
    ReDim SignalColCTC(numRows, numOTC)
    For n = 1 To numRows
        If (SignalColOTC(n, 1) = "OTC_Sell") Then
        list = list + 1
        SignalColCTC(n, list) = "OTC_Sell"
        For j = n + 1 To numRows
            If ((P_Ratio(j) < Mean) Or (Abs(P_Ratio(j)) > (1 + StopLoss) * Abs(P_Ratio(n)))) Then
            SignalColCTC(j, list) = "CTC_Buy"
            Else: SignalColCTC(j, list) = "Wait&See"
            End If
        Next j
        ElseIf (SignalColOTC(n, 1) = "OTC_Buy") Then
            list = list + 1
            SignalColCTC(n, list) = "OTC_Buy"
            For k = n + 1 To numRows
                If ((P_Ratio(k) > Mean) Or (Abs(P_Ratio(k)) < (1 - StopLoss) * Abs(P_Ratio(n)))) Then
                SignalColCTC(k, list) = "CTC_Sell"
                Else: SignalColCTC(k, list) = "Wait&See"
                End If
            Next k
        End If
    Next n
'Loop 3
    For o = 1 To numRows
        For list = 1 To numOTC
            If (SignalColCTC(o, list) = "CTC_Buy") Or (SignalColCTC(o, list) = "CTC_Sell") Then
                For p = o + 1 To numRows
                SignalColCTC(p, list) = "0"
                Next p
            End If
        Next list
    Next o
SignalCTC = SignalColCTC
End Function
```

Should this be a problem with Loop 3? I tried to put both loop 2 and loop 3 under one loop, but I get not even one trade signal but all zero this time.

```
 Function SignalCTC(Price1, Price2, Mean, SD, StopLoss)
    Dim i, j, k, m, n, o, p, numRows, numOTC, order, list, flag, finish
    numRows = Price1.Rows.Count
    Dim SignalColOTC()
    ReDim SignalColOTC(numRows, 1)
    Dim Price1Col()
    ReDim Price1Col(numRows)
    Dim Price2Col()
    ReDim Price2Col(numRows)
    Dim P_Ratio()
    ReDim P_Ratio(numRows)
    'Loop 1
    For i = 1 To numRows
        P_Ratio(i) = Price1(i) / Price2(i)
    Next i
    UpperLim = Mean + (2 * SD)
    LowerLim = Mean - (2 * SD)
    Count = 0
    flag = 0
    For i = 1 To numRows
        If (Count = 0 And (P_Ratio(i) < UpperLim) And (P_Ratio(i) > LowerLim)) Then
        Count = 0
        flag = 0
        SignalColOTC(i, 1) = "Wait&See"
        ElseIf (Count = 0 And (P_Ratio(i) > UpperLim)) Then
            Count = 1
            flag = 1
            SignalColOTC(i, 1) = "Wait&See"
            ElseIf (Count = 0 And (P_Ratio(i) < LowerLim)) Then
                Count = 1
                flag = -1
                SignalColOTC(i, 1) = "Wait&See"
                ElseIf (Count = 1 And flag = 1 And (P_Ratio(i) < UpperLim) And (P_Ratio(i) > Mean)) Then
                    Count = 0
                    flag = 0
                    SignalColOTC(i, 1) = "OTC_Sell"
                    ElseIf (Count = 1 And flag = -1 And (P_Ratio(i) > LowerLim) And (P_Ratio(i) < Mean)) Then
                        Count = 0
                        flag = 0
                        SignalColOTC(i, 1) = "OTC_Buy"
                        Else: SignalColOTC(i, 1) = "Wait&See"
        End If
    Next i
    numOTC = 0
    order = 0
    list = 0
    For i = 1 To numRows
        If (SignalColOTC(i, 1) = "OTC_Sell") Or (SignalColOTC(i, 1) = "OTC_Buy") Then
        numOTC = numOTC + 1
        Else: numOTC = numOTC
        End If
    Next i
    'Dim x
    x=1
    For Y=x to numRows
    'Loop 2
        Dim SignalColCTC()
        ReDim SignalColCTC(numRows, numOTC)
        For n = x To numRows
            If (SignalColOTC(n, 1) = "OTC_Sell") Then
            list = list + 1
            SignalColCTC(n, list) = "OTC_Sell"
            For j = n + 1 To numRows
                If ((P_Ratio(j) < Mean) Or (Abs(P_Ratio(j)) > (1 + StopLoss) * Abs(P_Ratio(n)))) Then
                SignalColCTC(j, list) = "CTC_Buy"
                Else: SignalColCTC(j, list) = "Wait&See"
                End If
            Next j
            ElseIf (SignalColOTC(n, 1) = "OTC_Buy") Then
                list = list + 1
                SignalColCTC(n, list) = "OTC_Buy"
                For k = n + 1 To numRows
                    If ((P_Ratio(k) > Mean) Or (Abs(P_Ratio(k)) < (1 - StopLoss) * Abs(P_Ratio(n)))) Then
                    SignalColCTC(k, list) = "CTC_Sell"
                    Else: SignalColCTC(k, list) = "Wait&See"
                    End If
                Next k
            End If
        Next n
    'Loop 3
        For o = x To numRows
            For list = 1 To numOTC
                If (SignalColCTC(o, list) = "CTC_Buy") Or (SignalColCTC(o, list) = "CTC_Sell") Then
                    For p = o + 1 To numRows
                    SignalColCTC(p, list) = "0"
                    Next p
                End If
                x = p
            Next list
        Next o
    Next Y
    SignalCTC = SignalColCTC
    End Function
```

Comment: I would love to help you on this but you should consider that debugging a full function for algo-trading signals generation is a big deal here. Could you please add some more specifics (e.g. input / expected output) and try to debug a bit yourself in order to isolate the problem?

Comment: Hey Matteo, Thank you so much for the response. I definitely have some inputs and outputs data for my code. however, I need to have 10 "reputations" to upload files or screen shots. Do you mind to give me your email address so that I can email you my input/output data?(My ultimate problem is that I can only get ONE pair trade out of 20 year testing period.)

Comment: You can upload them on [IMGUR](http://imgur.com/) and post the link, I will update your question for you.

Comment: Thanks! Here's the link of the output screenshot: http://imgur.com/a/086Px

Comment: (1) I got the Mean and Standard Deviation from a Moving average calculation. You can change values in cell K2 to get different MA (MA50,MA200,etc) and s.d. (2) The area highlighted in yellow is the final output I am looking for. From "OTC_Buy" to "CTC_Sell" is a full set of pair trade. However, I could not get any other trade after the first trade. (3) If I repeat the same code, I still get get only one trade (highlighted in green).  Ideally, the start point in green area (OTC_Sell) should be captured under the yellow area. It is the start of second trade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

interesting problem here. had a quick look through your code and nothing jumps out. Loop 3 seems fine to me, and didn't seem critical anyway.

maybe the logic you're implementing isn't quite what you want? I've added my commented version (no real changes except tabbing). might be a good approach for you to do similar to check loop 1 and 2 are doing what you want them to.

also, I assume mean and SD inputs are of the price ratios? why not just work them out in the function?

lastly, make sure when you're declaring variables in future you specify data types. can avoid errors and confusion down the line. e.g. 'dim i as integer'

```
Function SignalCTC(Price1, Price2, Mean, SD, StopLoss)

    Dim i, j, k, m, n, o, p, numRows, numOTC, order, list, flag, finish

    numRows = Price1.Rows.Count

    Dim SignalColOTC()
    ReDim SignalColOTC(numRows, 1)
    Dim Price1Col()
    ReDim Price1Col(numRows)
    Dim Price2Col()
    ReDim Price2Col(numRows)
    Dim P_Ratio()
    ReDim P_Ratio(numRows)

    'calculate ratios
    For i = 1 To numRows
        P_Ratio(i) = Price1(i) / Price2(i)
    Next i

    UpperLim = Mean + (2 * SD)
    LowerLim = Mean - (2 * SD)
    Count = 0
    flag = 0

    'Loop 1
    'identify possible opening events
    For i = 1 To numRows
        'if no events (within limits), reset
        If (Count = 0 And (P_Ratio(i) < UpperLim) And (P_Ratio(i) > LowerLim)) Then
            Count = 0
            flag = 0
            SignalColOTC(i, 1) = "Wait&See"
        'if exceeds for the first time
        ElseIf (Count = 0 And (P_Ratio(i) > UpperLim)) Then
            Count = 1
            flag = 1
            SignalColOTC(i, 1) = "Wait&See"
        'if under limit for the first time
        ElseIf (Count = 0 And (P_Ratio(i) < LowerLim)) Then
            Count = 1
            flag = -1
            SignalColOTC(i, 1) = "Wait&See"
        'if already exceeded once and now within limits
        ElseIf (Count = 1 And flag = 1 And (P_Ratio(i) < UpperLim) And (P_Ratio(i) > Mean)) Then
            Count = 0
            flag = 0
            SignalColOTC(i, 1) = "OTC_Sell"
        'if were under limit once and now within limits
        ElseIf (Count = 1 And flag = -1 And (P_Ratio(i) > LowerLim) And (P_Ratio(i) < Mean)) Then
            Count = 0
            flag = 0
            SignalColOTC(i, 1) = "OTC_Buy"
        Else
            SignalColOTC(i, 1) = "Wait&See"
        End If
    Next i

    numOTC = 0
    order = 0
    list = 0

    'count opening events
    For i = 1 To numRows
        If (SignalColOTC(i, 1) = "OTC_Sell") Or (SignalColOTC(i, 1) = "OTC_Buy") Then
            numOTC = numOTC + 1
        Else
            'numOTC = numOTC 'redundant, don't need
        End If
    Next i

    'Loop 2
    'identify closing events
    Dim SignalColCTC()
    ReDim SignalColCTC(numRows, numOTC)

    For n = 1 To numRows
        If (SignalColOTC(n, 1) = "OTC_Sell") Then
            list = list + 1 'scroll to next column
            SignalColCTC(n, list) = "OTC_Sell" 'we know this is the sale event
            For j = n + 1 To numRows 'remaining rows
                'if hits mean, or makes a big loss
                If ((P_Ratio(j) < Mean) Or (Abs(P_Ratio(j)) > (1 + StopLoss) * Abs(P_Ratio(n)))) Then
                    SignalColCTC(j, list) = "CTC_Buy" 'close position
                Else
                    SignalColCTC(j, list) = "Wait&See"
                End If
            Next j
        ElseIf (SignalColOTC(n, 1) = "OTC_Buy") Then 'logic repeated for sale
            list = list + 1
            SignalColCTC(n, list) = "OTC_Buy"
            For k = n + 1 To numRows
                If ((P_Ratio(k) > Mean) Or (Abs(P_Ratio(k)) < (1 - StopLoss) * Abs(P_Ratio(n)))) Then
                    SignalColCTC(k, list) = "CTC_Sell"
                Else
                    SignalColCTC(k, list) = "Wait&See"
                End If
            Next k
        End If
    Next n

    'Loop 3
    'just filling zeros after position is closed
    For o = 1 To numRows
        For list = 1 To numOTC
            If (SignalColCTC(o, list) = "CTC_Buy") Or (SignalColCTC(o, list) = "CTC_Sell") Then
                For p = o + 1 To numRows
                    SignalColCTC(p, list) = "0"
                Next p
            End If
        Next list
    Next o

    SignalCTC = SignalColCTC

End Function
```

**EDIT:**

Looking through the procedure, I expect the output matrix will look something like:

SignalColCTC:

```
OTC_Buy     Null        Null
Wait&See    Null        Null
Wait&See    OTC_Sell    Null
Wait&See    Wait&See    Null
CTC_Sell    Wait&See    Null
0           CTC_Buy     OTC_Buy
0           0           Wait&See
```

(N.B. I think nulls become zeros later)

Which seems reasonable to me. Maybe what you are trying to do is transform the pairs into a single column? It seems in the image you uploaded that this is what you want.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my question. Your comments are exactly what I am doing here. So my problem is just the last loop 3 where you stated as "just filling zeros after position is closed". What I really want is not only to fill zeros when the position is closed but to re-start the 1st and 2nd loop (identify open/close condition) so that we can re-open another new pair-trading position. Right now what loop 3 does is just finalizing the entire procedure: by all means, I can only get ONE pair trade over a 20 year period, using the current code.

Comment: Hi Miss Palmer! Thank you so much! I think that's exactly the answer I am looking for. So I should not do transform the pairs into a single column but leave them into multiple columns. And the question leftover is how to create a system to calculate each trades and profits. But I get my outputs at least. Thanks!

Comment: ah, happy to help teresa! yes each column should contain a different pair (though the last may not be closed out). well now you know when you buy them and when you sell them, and you have the prices in the original price arrays... shouldn't be too hard :P is this for uni/college btw? what course are you studying?